# ffmpeg avio_open() failed to open output file for writing encoded streams

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, codec

i am trying to convert  raw PCM into mp4 using ffmpeg ported for android.I am facing a problem in which the avio_open  return negative value saying Could not open sample.mp4  which is the output file saved in sdcard.i have given filepath like /sdcard/sample.mp4 .

```
avio_open(&oc->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)  returns -2
```

/* open the output file, if needed */

```
 if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
     if (avio_open(&oc->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s'\n", filename);
         return 1;
     }
 }
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but im my case I had codec and muxer enabled. Solved my problem by enabling the file protocol --enable-protocol=file.

Comment: hi did u muxed both audio and video  together  for example aac and h264  matching time line

Comment: @Dmytro what was the codec in your case?Were you trying to write on to a file(Saving the stream)?

Comment: In my case it was mpeg4. The task was to re-encode video stream from vlib to mpeg4 and save to file (mp4) without audio.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the ffmpeg for enabling the mp4.Have you done that.For that you have to enable the muxer and codec(coder-decoder) for mp4 format in the build.sh file in the ffmpeg root directory.Codec is I think it is MPEG4.Build it and then use it for MP4 file.